# Which language model technique should be used with a low-resource language?

Tags: natural-language-processing, language-model

I am working with a language for which the amount of text available is relatively small (less than a billion words), what techniques exist? In particular, is it worth using a transformer or is it better to use more traditional techniques?

The aim is to generate texts in continuation of a given prompt.

Comment: have you taken a look to the [spacy pretrained models documentation](https://spacy.io/models)? They support quite a lot of languages already, see left bar in the linked page